# WPF, xaml, list->floater->paragraph arrangement - problem with margin bottom

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Green" Padding="0">
            <Figure HorizontalAnchor="ColumnLeft" Margin="0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightCoral">
                <List Padding="18,0,0,0">
                    <ListItem Background="LightGray">
                        <Paragraph Background="Ivory">
                            We are getting closer to the final version now! This release includes several accessibility, performance and reliability fixes across the major framework libraries.
                        </Paragraph>
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
            </Figure>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

This code in xaml produces the following output:

[image]

Green and red border is only for illustration purposes.
Here you can see that the paragraph has an additional margin at the bottom.
In case the text in the ListItem is only single line, the margin isn't there:
[image]
Does anyone know what is happening here?
I would like to avoid this additional margin, becauses it causes design problems.
I need the arrangement with the paragraph -> floater -> list.

Hopefully anyone can help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me setting the `LineHeight` of the outermost paragraph fixes it on my end and removes the additional space. Try the following and see if it works for you:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Green" Padding="0" LineHeight="0.0034">
            <Figure HorizontalAnchor="ColumnLeft" Margin="0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightCoral">
                <List Padding="18,0,0,0">
                    <ListItem Background="LightGray">
                        <Paragraph Background="Ivory">
                            We are getting closer to the final version now! This release includes several accessibility, performance and reliability fixes across the major framework libraries.
                        </Paragraph>
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
            </Figure>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: you could just simply set a lowest value like LineHeight="0.005", that should also work

Comment: Yeah your right, the Margin fits a lot better with the minimum value, I've edited it